# How to avoid .prev().prev().prev() OR how to look up an item with a class before the current one

Tags: jquery

I looked up the whole jQuery Docs, but i doesn't found anything:
Is it possible to search an element before the current one with a specific class?
I thought this will work, but it doesn't:

```
$(this).prev('.bar');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ejh5G/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
 $('.d').prevAll('.a').css('color','red');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ejh5G/1/)

To address Jan's point, you can do this:

```
$('.d').prevAll('.a').first().css('color','red');
```

Comment: What if there are multiple `.a`s? Only the last one should be selected, isn't it so?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Fair enough, I threw a `.first()` in there. Interestingly, `.first()` does pick the first element working backwards and not the first element as it would appear in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) :

```
$(this).prevAll('.bar');// all elements    
$(this).prevAll('.bar').eq(0); //first element
$(this).prevAll('.bar:last'); //last element
```

Comment: What if there are multiple `.bar`s? Only the last one should be selected, isn't it so?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.d').prevAll('.a').first().css('color','red');
```

`.prevAll()`  -- Will select all the previous elements with `class a`

`.first()`  -- Will make sure only the first element in the list is selected.

Answer (score 1):

`.prevUntil` should work,

```
$('.d').prevUntil('.a').last().prev().css('color','red');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ejh5G/3/